# How to confirm integrity of Electrum wallet created using BIP39 mnemonic?

Tags: electrum, mnemonic-seed

Given paper backup of 24-word BIP39 mnemonic and passphrase, how can one confirm integrity of Electrum wallet given "Wallet" / "Seed" is greyed out?

Comment: I logged in as a different user on the same pc and recovered a wallet using the seed.  The seed generates the private key, and, so far as I can tell, is the same private key.  I haven't confirmed that the private key is the same, but that would be the point of the seed.